# import list as values of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this list:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and I convert to a dataframe using:

```
record = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

I get this:

```
     0
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
```

How do I get this instead, thanks??

```
     0    1    2    3
0    a    b    c    d
```

Comment: Dont know if this question is considered a duplicate but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882965/python-list-to-pandas-dataframe) is a link that goes into ways of formatting your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transpose()`

```
record = pd.DataFrame(list).transpose()
record
    Out[3]: 
       0  1  2  3
    0  a  b  c  d
```

Additionally, you can use:

```
pd.DataFrame(list).T
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass in list as [list]

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
record = pd.DataFrame([list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose it into that format with T

```
record = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

I liked the look of the other `([data])` solution posted, so I thought I'd check which was fastest for interest:

```
%timeit record = pd.DataFrame(data).T
820 µs ± 181 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit record = pd.DataFrame([data])
981 µs ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So it appears that Pandas T does have a performance advantage over building the list within a list first. This held true with 400 entries in the list as well.

And as noted elsewhere - it's not good practice to redefine list as it's a system keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

L = ['a','b','c','d']

df = pd.DataFrame([L])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 a b c d
```

I recommend you don't use the word "list" to name your list.